Coefficient of determination with binary prediction
The coefficient of determination $R^2$ is a popular measure of regression performance that compares the mean squared-deviation of predictions to the variance of the actual data. If instead of regression we consider binary classification, we can line up the True Positive ($\small{TP}$), False Positive ($\small{FP}$), True Negative ($\small{TN}$), and False Negative ($\small{FN}$) parts on a predicted-vs-actual plot as would commonly be used to understand $R^2$.
Turning the handle on how this feeds into the $R^2$ formula we end up with an expression for 'binarized' $R^2$ of
$$
\small{BR}^2 = 1-(1-{\small{ACC}})\frac{(N+P)^2}{NP}
$$
where $N$ is the number of negative cases ($N=\small{TN}+\small{FN}$), $P$ is the number of positive cases, and the accuracy $\small{ACC}=\frac{\small{TP}+\small{TN}}{N+P}$. This expression is nice because for imbalanced data it penalises the "just predict the majority class" method quite strongly.
Would anyone be able to provide a reference where I can learn more about how this expression has been used elsewhere and any other properties it may have? If it is connected to other known binary classification metrics that would also be great to hear about.


Welcome to Cross Validated! Isn't this the Matthews correlation? $//$ Related and Related $//$ Do make sure you really have categorical outcomes to assess. Many so-called "classification" models do not make classifications, with logistic regressions and neural networks being among the models often considered to do classification when they do not. Details here..

Thanks @Dave! Your links are very similar to this - I think there comparing the error rate of the model under analysis to the error rate of a model that predicts just the majority class, vs here comparing the error rate of the model under analysis to the error rate of a model that randomly predicts each class in proportion to their prevalence. That gives me more to investigate!

Where did you get that $BR^2$ equation? I think you're alluding the the Matthews correlation, though I have not gotten your equation to exactly match the correlation calculation.
